# Python: set variable in one class and use/get in different class

Tags: python, python-3.x, getter-setter, getter

I am new in Python, please ignore my explanation mentioned below, Basically I want a middle class(setter/getter) so that I can set values in one class and get values from any other class. I tried to make small program just for the solution purpose.

I am setting variable in class `A`

```py
import sg
import testB

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = sg.SG()

    def run(self):
        self.s.setTest('123')
        testB.B().run()

A().run()
```

using set get method class:

```py
class SG():
    test = ''

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = ''
        print('I am in init')

    def setTest(self, test1):
        print('I am in set')
        self.test = test1

    def getTest(self):
        print('I am in get')
        return self.test
```

trying to retrieve variable value in class `B`:

```py
import sg

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        # self.s = sg.SG()

    def run(self):
        print("i am in B run")
        sg.SG.getTest()
```

Comment: When you create an instance of a class, in this case its `sg.SG()`, the instance will be local to whichever .py file it's called at. To solve your problem, you'll need to somehow share the; example `x = sg.SG()` with all the classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how to share x in all classes as there are many classes and I dont want to share it as an argument

Comment: It's generally not a great practice, but you could make a global variable. Simply a variable outside the class and you can access that variable with *the_python_file_name.the_variable_name*

Comment: you mean xyz= '' in a simple python file and I can access that in different classes, however if I want to run classes in thread, does python provide single copy of xyz to each thread?